# Reliable WinSock API that determines which endian is used on my machine

Tags: c++, winsock, endianness, winsock2, c++98

I wanted to use [ntohs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740075(v=vs.85).aspx) initially, but the following section in the Remarks forced me to ask here for help:

> If the netshort parameter is already in host byte order, then this
>   function will reverse it. It is up to the application to determine if
>   the byte order must be reversed.

I could try something like this:

```
short int i= 0x1;
char *c= (char*)&i;

if(c[0] == 1)  // little endian, use ntohs
```

but I was wondering if there is Winsock API function that does the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I did not test it, the [WSANtohs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741663(v=vs.85).aspx) function does not include a remark to have the application check if the byte order must be reversed. It does say that it checks the network byte order:

> The socket passed in the s parameter is used to determine the network
>   byte order required based on the Winsock catalog protocol entry
>   associated with the socket.